# Oauth 2.0 implementation in PHP

Tags: php, xampp, oauth-2.0

I am trying to expose our APIs to the clients and users and I want to allow them to access it only in case when they authorize themselves from our database using Oauth 2.0. I am planning to write it in core PHP. I have done enough research to find it on web. I have seen few codes on http://oauth.net/code under PHP section, but still not able to setup it in running condition. Can someone tell me the exact procedure to setup it on windows xampp machine or any library that I can deploy it directly.